# Unzip file from server http

Tags: android, unzip

I have a problem to unzip a file received from server. I send a request, and server show me a text with code characters :S

With this code i receive a zip from server, but i need this text file unziped, and show in a EdText.

```
public void postLoginData() {

    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
            "http://localhost:80/MOBILE/MBSERVER.V25?");
    try {
        String VENDED_VEN = "2", EMPRES_CFG = "1", VERSAO_CFG = "100", function = "GetMARCAS", REQUERY = null;

        comando = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comando);
        // String PLS = comando.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> values = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);

        values = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EMPRES", EMPRES_CFG));
        values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("USUARI", VENDED_VEN));
        values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("VERSAO", VERSAO_CFG));
        values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ORIGEM", "AD"));
        values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FUNCAO", function));
        values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RQUERY", REQUERY));


        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(values));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        Log.w("LOG", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.w("LOG", "VALUES:"+values);

        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent())
                .toString();



        Log.w("LOG", str);
        if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
            Log.w("LOG", "TRUE");
            result.setText("Login successful");

        } else {
            Log.w("LOG", "FALSE");
            result.setText(str);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    // Read response until the end
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Return full string
    return total;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == ok) {
        postLoginData();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a standard zip file, you can use the `java.util.zip` package.

Here's an example of unzipping an archive that has a folder in it, and writing it to a file.

```
FileInputStream zipInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(cacheDir, zipFileName));
FileOutputStream datOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(cacheDir, datFileName));

// unzip and process ZIP file
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(zipInputStream);
ZipEntry ze = null;
// loop through archive
while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    if (ze.getName().toString().equals("myfolder/myfile.dat")) { // change this to whatever your folder/file is named inside the archive
        while ((bufferLength = zis.read(buffer, 0, 1023)) != -1) {
            datOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
     }
     zis.closeEntry();
}
```

Comment: I receive in a string     
     String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();          
Like this: 2¤¿Öïé·t­-ŸÜ;2Iñ±k­½ý¿¿~óÍ÷WïB¿üðÓï?ÿúËï?þö¯? hehehehehehe

Can I receive this archive in a zip? How?
And how can I save it in device?
Thx! :)

Comment: I should've specified. Just put your input stream into a file output stream into your temp / cache directory that Android gives you. Then read it using the zip input stream, and you can write the file out, or do whatever you want to with it. You can't just do it in a string. You'll have to write to disk.