# String received from the server displays special characters as "?"

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, http

I have a servlet that gets some data from cloud sql, creates a java object, converts it to json and appends it to the response writer.

The problem is this data may contain strings with special characters such as "ç" and "ã".

The servlet authenticates the request and then does the following:

```
resp.getWriter().append(new Gson().toJson(new MyDataType(resultset)));
resp.setContentType("application/json");
```

I've also tried setting the response encoding to "utf-8", put this

```
<property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
```

under system properties at the appengine-web.xml file, but nothing worked.

The code in the client is as follows:

```
URL u = new URL(myurl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8");
MyDataType l = new Gson().fromJson(in, MyDataType.class);
```

What do i have to do to make strings display correctly?

Comment: Looks like that response stream is compressed? If so, you need to decompress it before using Gson.

Comment: And how do i do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485173/unzip-file-from-server-http. Many other links available in SO, I think.

Comment: Well i just verified that this is not the case... The response is not compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the server code to

```
resp.setContentType("application/json");
resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
resp.getWriter().append(new Gson().toJson(new MyDataType(rs3)));
```

solved the issue.